# How to filter this criteria based vertically combined queries blank row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using this to successfully (or almost) query multiple columns into 01 based on a criteria. This, however, shows a blank row I can't seem to get rid of.

```
=iferror({
query({Orders!A:FF}, "select Col144 where Col7 matches '"& P4 &"' and not Col144 contains '#N/A' and not Col144 matches '-' and Col144 is not null");
query({Orders!A:FF}, "select Col151 where Col7 matches '"& P4 &"' and not Col151 contains '#N/A' and not Col151 matches '-' and Col151 is not null");
query({Orders!A:FF}, "select Col162 where Col7 matches '"& P4 &"' and not Col162 contains '#N/A' and not Col162 matches '-' and Col162 is not null")
},"")
```

I've tried filter it in the query criteria set, but it still shows.
This is current result, with always this blank row:
[image]

How to accomplish it?

Here's some [mock](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing) data for tests.

Thank you!

Comment: For same range why you are using 3 query. You can try one query `=Query({Orders!A:FF}, "select Col144, Col151, Col162 where Col7 matches '"& P4 &"' and not Col144 contains '#N/A' and not Col144 matches '-' and Col144 is not null")`

Comment: I guess I need to that so that this is combined vertically...? I'll try again with the ```is not null``` again. Thanks, @Harun24hr!

Comment: Can you show some sample data? Share a dummy workbook.

Comment: Just added it above, @Harun24hr! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You have two sheet. Which one is your raw data `items` sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you just want to remove the blank rows from the returned Query. You can try adding another Query instead of filter to remove the blanks.

From your sample sheet I edited the existing formula

**Try:**

```
=QUERY({QUERY({D1:G10},"select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&B2&"'",0);QUERY({D1:G10},"select Col3 where Col1 matches '"&B2&"'",0);QUERY({D1:G10},"select Col4 where Col1 matches '"&B2&"'",0)},"Select Col1 where Col1 is not NULL")
```

**Result:**
[image]

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I work up with this as an attempt I'd make. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See the new tab called MK.Help where you will find this formula to show only items with variance 2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(D2:I2&"|"&A4:A6&"|"&B4:B6&"|"&D4:I6),"|",0,0),"where Col2 = 2"))
```

The query(split(Flatten( technique has become the most common way to "unpivot" data since the Flatten function was discovered several years ago hidden in the back end of Google Sheets.

Comment: Hey, Mat! Thanks a lot. I'll have to take the one above, as this is what I thought of when I woke up today and it returns the exact expected result. Learned some more with your answer though. Thank you